# Rpart speed : number of variables more important than number of splits to try

Tags: r, rpart

I thought that the number of splits to try would have a huge impact on performance, and thus decided to split the information contained in a non ordered factor with 92 levels, in some variables with a few ordered levels.

But after testing, it was the contrary and I couldn't find by myself an explanation, I was thinking someone may have more information on the reason a such thing is happening

I made a quick example of the behaviour in the linked code.

```
library(rpart)

test = data.frame(a=sample(0:1,1000000,replace=T),b=sample(0:1,1000000,replace=T),
                  c=sample(0:1,1000000,replace=T),d=sample(0:1,1000000,replace=T),
                  e=sample(0:90,1000000,replace=T),f=rnorm(1000000,0,1))
test$a <- as.factor(test$a)
test$b <- as.factor(test$b)
test$c <- as.factor(test$c)
test$d <- as.factor(test$d)
test$e <- as.factor(test$e)

as.numeric(system.time((temp <- rpart(f~a+b+c+d,data= test , method="anova",cp=0.0)))[1],maxsurrogate=0)
as.numeric(system.time((temp <- rpart(f~e,data= test , method="anova",cp=0.0)))[1],maxsurrogate=0)


Rprof("test1.Rprof")
rpart(f~a+b+c+d,data= test , method="anova",cp=0.0)
Rprof()
Rprof("test2.Rprof")
rpart(f~e,data= test , method="anova",cp=0.0)
Rprof()

summaryRprof("test1.Rprof")
summaryRprof("test2.Rprof")
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: [`We have said that for a categorical predictor with m levels, all 2m−1 different possible splits are tested. When there are a large number of categories for the predictor, the computational burden of evaluating all of these subsets can become large.... Luckily, for any ordered outcome there is a computational shortcut that allows the program to find the best split using only m − 1 comparisons.`](http://www.mayo.edu/research/documents/biostat-61pdf/doc-10026699)

Comment: @rawr I agree with you, except that I'm not using ordered factor, as you can see in the example above by typing (is.ordered(test$e)), yet using only the variable e will lead to a faster computational time.